# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for everything is right from my side

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I'am unable resolve this issue. As soon as I imported the existence spring boot project or created by myself using spring initializer or using sts tool, Ia'm getting the error in POM.xml. I donnot why its giving the error. I have seen all the related issues in stackoverflow. Some said proxy should be added in setting.xml, other said internet connection but I have 40 mbps speed internet.

**ERROR : ** Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.techprimers:transactionality-demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.15.RELEASE from http://server:8081/artifactory/libs-release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.15.RELEASE from/to central (http://server:8081/artifactory/libs-release): server and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: what was the error, when u try mvn clean install ?

Comment: Sorry for that. See I have edited and posted the error.

Answer (score 0):

As from error, it is clear that maven is trying to download jars from  http://server:8081/ and it couldn't able to access it

If  http://server:8081/ is custom repository, try to check whether your are able to access it.

If you have no idea about  http://server:8081/ server. Then check your ~/.m2/settings.xml or /%maven_root%/conf/settings.xml.

Settings.xml has to be configured with accessible repository or try to setup new maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: Yea I have deleted old version maven and took new version maven. It worked for me.